# Execute Unix command from a python code

Tags: python, unix

```
diff -u <(echo "aba"| fold -w1) <(echo "abaa" | fold -w1)
```

I want to execute the above command from Python code. Below is the code I have written.

```
cmd = "diff -u < (echo 'aba'| fold -w1) < (echo 'abaa' | fold -w1)"
os.system(cmd)
```

Running the above code, I get `sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected` error. As per my knowledge the unix os can't parse the echo command which is inside the braces.

Help me fix this error.

Answer (score 3):

First, [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) is discouraged in favor of [`subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system). That's worth knowing because there's a lot of additional detail in the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) documentation, including this description of the `shell=True` parameter (emphasis added):

> On POSIX with `shell=True`, the **shell defaults to `/bin/sh`**.... Popen does the equivalent of:
>
> ```
> Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])
> ```

So now we know why your command doesn't work - it's not invoking Bash. As mhawke suggests you should instead invoke `bash` directly, but you should prefer the `subprocess` module over `os.system()`:

```
>>> subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'diff -u <(echo "aba"| fold -w1) <(echo "abaa" | fold -w1)'])
--- /dev/fd/63  2017-02-25 14:32:49.000000000 -0800
+++ /dev/fd/62  2017-02-25 14:32:49.000000000 -0800
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 a
 b
 a
+a
1
```

Note that, since we're explicitly invoking the Bash shell, we don't need `shell=True`, and since the command we're telling Bash to invoke is a single argument we don't need to repeatedly escape them, e.g. with `"""` as mhawke did.

Once you've verified this command works, you'll likely want to move away from simply invoking `call()` to one of `subprocess` other functions that are more scripting-friendly, such as [`run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), which returns a `CompletedProcess` object you can inspect.

As Jean-François Fabre suggests you can do a lot more powerful things with `subprocess` as well, including starting the `<()` substitutions as separate processes and piping them into a call to `diff`, thus avoiding needing to invoke `bash` or write Bash syntax in Python. It's more verbose, but more extensible and maintainable.

Comment: and portable too, you'd only have to install `diff` & `fold` on windows.

Answer (score 2):

The command runs fine in `bash`, however, `os.system()` is executing the command in `/bin/sh`. You can check with:

```
>>> os.system('echo $0')
sh
0
```

The command fails when executed with `/bin/sh`:

```
[mhawke@localhost-localdomain ~]$ /bin/sh
sh-4.3$ diff -u <(echo "aba"| fold -w1) <(echo "abaa" | fold -w1)
sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh-4.3$
```

You can explicitly run the command in `bash` like this:

```
>>> os.system("""bash -c 'diff -u <(echo "aba"| fold -w1) <(echo "abaa" | fold -w1)'""")
--- /dev/fd/63  2017-02-26 09:18:14.633395225 +1100
+++ /dev/fd/62  2017-02-26 09:18:14.633395225 +1100
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 a
 b
 a
+a
256
```

---

Since you are probably interested in the output of the command you would ordinarily be able to use `subprocess.check_output()` to execute the command and collect its output. Unfortunately `diff` likes to return non-zero exit codes when it detects differences in the input files, so that prevents simply using `check_output`. You can cheat by piping `diff`'s output through `cat`:

```
>>> from subprocess import check_output
>>> output = check_output(['bash', '-c', 'diff -u <(echo "aba"| fold -w1) <(echo "abaa" | fold -w1) | cat'])
>>> print(output)
b'--- /dev/fd/63\t2017-02-26 10:02:56.814044987 +1100\n+++ /dev/fd/62\t2017-02-26 10:02:56.814044987 +1100\n@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@\n a\n b\n a\n+a\n'

>>> print(str(output, encoding='utf8'))
--- /dev/fd/63  2017-02-26 10:02:56.814044987 +1100
+++ /dev/fd/62  2017-02-26 10:02:56.814044987 +1100
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 a
 b
 a
+a
```

Comment: the best way would be to use 3 `Popen` objects chained together with pipes.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: that's true, but it depends on your point of view. OP is asking about `os.system()`.

Comment: I was not criticizing your answer but the question :) the +1 is mine. I should have commented the question, not the answer. I can't blame you for not trying to write the 3 pipes in python!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: no problem, I didn't take it as criticism - thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

or you could

```
import subprocess
cmd = """bash -c 'diff -u <(echo "aba"| fold -w1) <(echo "abaa" | fold -w1)'"""

ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = ps.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: what's the point of using `subprocess` instead of `os.system()` if you're not going all the way with 3 subprocess objects and drop the `shell=True` part?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre "the best way would be to use 3 Popen objects chained together with pipes." is this what you mean?